# Programa escrever na textbox de outro

Tags: c#

Olá! Usei o programa "Exe Lock" pra bloquear uns arquivos meus, tudo funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que eu estava tentando abrir o arquivo bloqueado com um programa em C# e o próprio programa escrever na textbox que pede a senha pra o outro ser aberto, não sei explicar bem como é mas aqui vai uma imagem:
[image]
Eu já tentei passar a senha como argumento tipo assim:

```
Process.Start("Arquivo bloqueado.exe", "-password 0909288");
```

Mas não deu nem um pouco certo, também tentei colocar um redirectoutput e inserir a senha e mesmo assim nada...
Alguém tem alguma ideia, e de preferência que não seja gambiarra?

Comment: Pra funcionar da forma que você testou, a aplicação deveria ter sido implementada com recurso para receber parâmetros. Se não funcionou, é por que não é o caso. Não conheço C#, mas sei que o Windows possibilita a simulação de teclas pressionadas. Só que para isso, tua aplicação deve ficar em segundo plano, e a aplicação que deve receber o conteúdo em foco.

Comment: Eu mandei um e-mail pra os desenvolvedores, espero que eles possibilitem isso :D

Comment: Existe alguma forma de saber quais parâmetros um programa recebe? Pode ser que teja um parâmetro chamado passw por exemplo

Comment: Que eu saiba não. Só vendo a documentação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podemos tentar algo assim:

```
    Process processo = Process.Start("SICON.EXE");
    IntPtr h = processo.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    processo.WaitForInputIdle(); // Isso aqui foi de extrema importância :D.
    SendKeys.SendWait("senhaaqui");
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: Vou tentar agora mesmo, obrigado pela sugestão :)

Comment: Cara você é um Deus!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Eu vou postar a forma que eu fiz pra ficar perfeito ok?

Comment: Show de bola! Acrescentei seu código como correto!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver com a ideia do Felipe M. Martins, mas vou postar aqui a forma que eu deixei pra ficar bem limpo:

```
Process processo = Process.Start("SICON.EXE");
IntPtr h = processo.MainWindowHandle;
SetForegroundWindow(h);
processo.WaitForInputIdle(); // Isso aqui foi de extrema importância :D.
SendKeys.SendWait("senhaaqui");
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```