# Passar o Login\Senha\Enter para uma aplicacao externa. C# com Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Usei o código passado em

[Programa escrever na textbox de outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173788/programa-escrever-na-textbox-de-outro)

Para escrever o login/senha no programa de outro fabricante.

Fiz assim:

```
Process processo = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\ZKTeco\ZKAccess3.5\Access.exe");
IntPtr h = processo.MainWindowHandle;
SetForegroundWindow(h);
processo.WaitForInputIdle(); // Isso aqui foi de extrema importância :D.

SendKeys.SendWait("admin");
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
SendKeys.SendWait("admin");
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Ele ate chama o sistema, mas nao passa os valores para os respectivos campos.

Comment: Obrigado por editar o topico Joao Martins, sou novo e nao sei usar o forum ainda...

Comment: ao abrir o programa o foco está no primeiro campo de texto? exemplo, se você abre o programa manualmente e só digita, ele preenche o campo do login?

Comment: Sim, esta´com o foco no campo Login